# Image recognition for text in React Native

Tags: ios, image, react-native, image-recognition

This may be a crazy question but I've seen done with apps. Is there any kind of API that can be used to recognition the text within an image (the way chase recognizes numbers on a check) OR, is there an API that can be used to search (lets say google) for information based off an image? Example would be if I took a picture of a business logo, google will search for a business listing that fits that logo?

I know crazy question but I want to know if it can even be done. If it can, can it be used with React Native? Thanks!

Comment: Googling `react native text recognition` seems to yield a useful result (Tesseract), have you checked it out?

Comment: Actually no I have not. I was search all types of things but not the most logical one lol. Thanks I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

The React Native Tesseract package only supports Android.  iOS support is pending but no timeline when it will be done.

The pure Javascript implementation of Tesseract would offer cross-platform support in React Native.
http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/

Comment: Yeah I saw it was only supported Android. I will look into this option thanks!

Comment: Hmmm this doesn't seem to work either. I keep getting 'Can't find variable: location'. I removed this from the node_modules index (just to see if that was the only issue), but now I get 'Can't find variable: worker'. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like the JS port uses APIs that aren't supported by the JS engine that React Native uses.  https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/55