# How to Scan and Extract data from IDs and Passports

Tags: react-native, plugins, scanning

I want scan and extract data from IDs and Passports, Which free plugins I use? Or how do I do it, To read the data and add this data to form.

Comment: Interesting.. Could you please provide more info on IDs, in past we have done project to extract information from US driving license. But it has PDF417 barcode which stores information. If you have similar type of ID card then you can use either barcode scanner to scan and retrieve information or you can use TT800 id card scanner which gives all the information from barcode or magnetic strip over the card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460965/image-recognition-for-text-in-react-native) question on how to read text from images.

Having said text, since each field always has a fixed text before identifying what it is, if you know the id formats you want to support, you can implement that fairly easily (The text between "Name:" and "Surname:" is the person's name, and so on).

To get the images, you should use something like react-native-camera, or, if you are using Expo, its Camera API.

Answer (score 3):

You divide the job into multiple steps

1. **Take a photo**
2. **Load the image**
3. **Image analyze** find an OCR npm package
4. **Pass the text into your fields via props** (or use the Context API)

Answer (score 3):

There are few OCR SDKs that enable you to do that. Check out https://github.com/Anyline/anyline-ocr-react-native-module or
https://github.com/jonathanpalma/react-native-tesseract-ocr#readme which supports only Android for now.